# Ошибка компиляции в Java: Неправильное использование параметризованного типа TouchAction в Appium

Tags: java, appium

Строка, которая вызывает недовольство IDE:

```
static TouchAction<> action = new TouchAction(driver);
```

Компилятор выдает следующую ошибку:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> TouchAction is a raw type. References to generic type TouchAction
> should be parameterized TouchAction is a raw type. References to
> generic type TouchAction should be parameterized Incorrect number
> of arguments for type TouchAction; it cannot be parameterized with
> arguments <>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инициализировал строку так:

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions;
 TouchActions action = new TouchActions(driver);
```

Вместо:

```
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
static TouchAction<> action = new TouchAction(driver);
```